# Neural Network to recognize accelerometer pattern

Tags: android, neural-network

I'm building an application for Android devices that requires it to recognize, by accelerometer data, the difference between walking noise and double tapping it. I'm trying to solve this problem using Neural Networks.

At the start it went pretty well, teaching it to recognize the taps from noise such as standing up/ sitting down and walking around at a slower pace. But when it came to normal walking it never seemed to learn even though I fed it with a large proportion of noise data.

**My question**: Are there any serious flaws in my approach? Is the problem based on lack of data?

#### The network

I've choosen a 25 input 1 output multi-layer perceptron, which I am training with backpropagation. The input is the changes in acceleration every 20ms and output ranges from -1 (for no-tap) to 1 (for tap). I've tried pretty much every constallation of hidden inputs there are, but had most luck with 3 - 10.

I'm using Neuroph's easyNeurons for the training and exporting to Java.

#### The data

My total training data is about 50 pieces double taps and about 3k noise. But I've also tried to train it with proportional amounts of noise to double taps.

The data looks like this (ranges from +10 to -10):

Sitting double taps: [image: Sitting double taps, fairly easy to determine.]

---

Fast walking:
[image: Fast walking and double tapping, not that easy]

So to reiterate my questions: Are there any serious flaws in my approach here? Do I need more data for it to recognize the difference between walking and double tapping? Any other tips?

**Update**

Ok so after much adjusting we've boiled the essential problem down to being able to recognize double taps while taking a brisk walk. Sitting and regular (in-house) walking we can solve pretty good.

Brisk walk
[image: Brisk walk]

So this is some test data of me first walking then stopping, standing still, then walking and doing 5 double taps while I'm walking.

If anyone is interested in the raw data, I linked it for the latest (brisk walk) data [here](http://www.2shared.com/file/6I2niK0b/walkx3_5dt.html?)

Comment: I (a neural network) see a clear difference between the two patterns. But: What if you double-tap when walking? Is it still possible to clearly differentiate which jerk was a tap and which one noise? If those two graphs are on the same scale, I'd say it would be hard to separate the noise peaks from the tap peaks.

Comment: You can see an example tap in the fast walking graph at around 400. That one has some unique qualities, but its not very clear cut.

Comment: Yes, I see that now. The thing to look out for is spiked deviations from the mean in both directions => tap. Of course the perceptron needs to learn this on its own. Two questions: 1. What do you provide as 'desired output' when training? 2. What are the 25 inputs? Are they a sliding window of the last 25 jerk samples?

Comment: 2. Yes exactly, the accelerometer data feeds me one reading every 20ms and I use a sliding window of 25 of those, so its a span of 0.5 sec. 
1. I give it 25 readings of an instance where there is a double tap present and label it with the output 1. 
Did I understand your questions correctly? Thanks for showing interest btw, much appreciated.

Comment: Do you slide across the inputs while teaching? e.g. Say you have 100 actual samples: Then you teach it with samples 1-25 as input, then 2-26 as input, then 3-27, and so on till you finally finish teaching with the window from 76-100.

Comment: Secondly, I see that a lot of the 'taps' in the quiet input, and the single 'tap' in the noisy input are more than 20 samples wide. Did you consider letting the perceptron see a wider window? (You could downsample if the number of inputs becomes too much)

Comment: No I did not try to teach it across the whole thing, only slight variations of it.

The input size it 25 wide, and I do not see anything that goes wider than that. But won't a wider range make it harder for it to generalize - ie do I need more data then?

Comment: I'm not sure about this.

Comment: I'll be fiddling around with a couple of the things you mentioned and update if I get any progress.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you considered that the "fast walking" and "fast walking + double tapping" signals might be too similar to differentiate using only accelerometer data? It may simply not be possible to achieve accuracy above a certain amount.

Otherwise, neural networks are probably a good choice for your data, and it still may be possible to get better performance out of them.

This very-useful paper (http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/publis/pdf/lecun-98b.pdf) recommends that you whiten your dataset so that it has a mean of zero and unit covariance.

Also, since your problem is a classification problem, you should make sure that you are training your network using a cross-entropy criteria (http://arxiv.org/pdf/1103.0398v1.pdf ) rather than RMSE. (I have no idea whether Neuroph supports cross-entropy or not.)

Another relatively simple thing you could try, as other posters suggested, is transforming your data. Using an FFT or DCT to transform your data to the frequency domain is relatively standard for time-series classification.

You could also try training networks on different sized windows and averaging the results.

If you want to try some more difficult NN architectures, you could look at the Time-Delay-Neural-Network (just google this for the paper), which takes multiple windows into account in its structure. It should be relatively straightforward to use one of the Torch libraries (http://www.torch.ch/) to implement this, but it might be hard to export the network to an Android environment.

Finally, another method of getting better classification performance in time-series data is to consider the relationships between adjacent labels. Conditional Neural Fields (http://code.google.com/p/cnf/ - note:I have never used this code) do this by integrating neural networks into conditional random fields, and, depending on the patterns of behavior in your actual data, may do a better job.

Comment: Thanks for your many advice. I think the general gist of this answer hits the nail on the head - I have to process the data to get a more distinguished set of features.

Answer (score 4):

Do you insist on using a neural network? If not, here is an idea:

Take a window of 0.5 seconds and consider the area under the curve (or since your signal is discrete, the sum of the absolute values of each sensor reading-- the red area in the attached image). You will probably find that that sum is high when the user is walking and much much lower when they are sitting and/or tapping. You can set a threshold above which you consider a given window to be taken while the user is walking. Alternatively, since you have labelled data, you can train any binary classifier to differentiate between walking and not walking.

You can probably improve your system by considering other features of the signal, such as how jagged the line is. If the phone is sitting on a table, the line will be almost flat. If the user is typing, the line will be kind of flat, and you will see a spike every now and then. If they are walking, you will see something like a sine wave.

[image]

Comment: Very interesting. No I'm definitely not set on using NN - I just want to solve the problem. The main issue right now is being able to see the difference between a brisk walk and a brisk walk with taps. I've updated the post with additional data. Think I'm in over my head here?

Comment: Another idea- look up "signal cross-correlation".
You could model the "walk with taps, WT" signal as the sum of "sitting and tapping, ST" and "walking, W". It could be the case this is a reasonable assumption in practice. Given a new signal S, compute crosscor(S,ST+W) and compare to crosscor (S,W).

Answer (score 1):

What probably would work is to filter the data using a [Fourier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform) transform first. Walking has a sinus like amplitude, your double taps would stand-out in the transform-result as a different frequency. I guess a neural network can than determine if the data contains your double tabs because it has the extra frequency (the double tabs frequency). Some questions remain:

1. How long the sample of data needs to be?
2. Can your phone do all the work it needs to do, does it have enough processing power?

You might even want to consider using the GPU for this.

Another option is to use the Fourier output and some good old [Fuzzy Logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzzy_logic).

This sound like fun...